# Retain checkbox state in angular when the scope changes

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, retain

below is a code snippet:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in ioStatusData">
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>{{data.IOStatusName}}</td>
    <td>{{data.IOLabel}}</td>
    <td>{{data.IOStatus}}</td>
    <td>{{data.TestResult}}</td>
</tr>
```

`scope.ioStatusData` keeps updating every 5 secs.I want to retain checkbox state (checked or unchecked) even when `scope.ioStatusData` changes.

Comment: You probably want `ng-repeat="data in ioStatusData track by data.IOStatusName"` (assuming IOStatusName uniquely identifies a data).

Comment: since checkbox is inside the ngRepeat, setting ngModel alone on it would not help cause that would be updated through ngRepeat update cycle. So use one time binding alongside ngModel. `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="::checkboxModel">.`

Comment: suggest add checked value{IOStatusName:xx,checked:true}, and bind to checkbox, when list changes reinit the checked value

Answer (score 0):

You need to have

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheckboxIsChecked[$index]">
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.myCheckboxIsChecked = [];
```

And your checbox state will be there even if the values of your array are changing.

Comment: @JBNizet Can you be more explicit.

Comment: Well, just try your suggestion, and you'll see that it doesn't work: http://plnkr.co/edit/ErNxtYbQ8egFCoU9OtAe?p=preview

Comment: No need for that ugly $parent. Just initialize the array in the controller: http://plnkr.co/edit/rwtJkglsg7ueSHrJyAwz?p=preview

Comment: Thre is one thing that is unclear to me - ng-repeat creates scopes for each item in the array, and if not using $parent,  the current scope of the item will be the scope created by iterator. Than how it comes that if not using parent, it still uses the variable defined in the scope of controller and not inner scope of the items inside the ng-repeat?

Comment: The scope of the ng-repeat inherits from the controller scope. So if you initialize `myCheckboxIsChecked` in the controller scope, it will be inherited in the ng-repeat scope, angular will find it there, and will update it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check the row is selected or not ignoring the data. Define an object in your controller that store the row state like

```
$scope.rowState = {};
```

And change the `checkbox` model like

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="rowState['index_' + $index]" />
```

Actually `ng-repeat` create dynamically `rowState` object like `rowState.index_0`, `rowState.index_1`

Check the [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/id5CcrM9QdF3EzrTCNUU?p=preview)